# What should a dependency management framework do?

Tags: .net, architecture, build, build-automation, dependency-management

I started to write an open-source, free dependency management framework for .NET/C++. Asking the question here I'm trying  not to create yet another one no one needs. This desperate evening hobby of mine began after hopelessly trying to adopt tons of existing ones which couldn't satisfy my humble work and hobby needs:

- simple command-line interface which just works without requiring tangled ms-specific deployments and UI plugins; to be able to easily use it in a CI build script, or as a part of NAnt or MSBuild exec interface
- simple directory-based package repositories if you don't want to set up a repository server
- local package caching
- support for multiple repositories and repository chaining
- easy package compilation from a command line and publishing to a specific repository
- very simple package configuration file
- effective dependency tree resolution (i.e. dependencies of dependencies and deeper); conflicts detection; automatic dependency version upgrades;

Idea is simple if a solution has the following structure which is pretty standard across svn-based repositories:

```
/ (trunk?)
/include (3rdparty c++ header files)
/tools (some tools required to build your product, for example protobuf generator)
/other (random stuff which doesn't fit anywhere, like resources)
/lib (managed 3rdparty library binaries)
/src (the solution's source files)
```

In the root theres also .xml configuration file, describing your solution and containing:

- globally unique package id
- metadata (version, vendor, release notes etc)
- package dependencies (log4?, hibernate, boost etc) including version pattern, platform etc.
- files to take from /src folder in order to produce a package from your solution (if any)

Console tool allows to search repository for packages, resolve dependencies (they will be placed in /include, /lib and /tools folders), compile your package and publish it to a repository. /lib, /include, /tools folder content doesn't have to be commited to subversion, only the config xml in root folder.

The tool supports multiple repositories which are configured in an xml file located in user's home folder (if not overriden) where he can configure their priorities, locations, publishing options.

Written for .NET 4, but can easily refactor for Mono.

I won't paste the URL here to be banned for advertising.

Comment: I'm not very sure myself what is even a dependency management framework (never used things with such high level tools), still if this project is from your idea why don't you explore the cases of use for this program by personifying various persons with various goals to find out what should it do? For self motivated project I find this approach pretty good and effective

Comment: they say it's good, however you never know if people are being nice or saying truth :)

Comment: Point taken. Sometimes we need to do some radical changes to the project and try to "force" those changes to see what people would really like. Since this is a yet-to-be-done project, maybe you could read reviews and/or opinions about other dependency managers and try to find out the "things that the reviewer would like to see done". I've also done it some times and it worked

Comment: oh btw forgot to tell you. If you're looking for some sort of "inspiration" to do the project you could look at the rpm engine used in linux to meet program dependencies (in terms of libraries and such), maybe is not exactly what you want it does dependencies in other contexts (rpm is known to be complex, still, is one of the best doing it's job)